# Поместить в txt имена файлов bash

Tags: linux, файлы, bash, echo

Я бы хотел, используя командную строку, скопировать названия файлов и поместить их в текстовый файл. 
Их может быть больше и с другими названиями но как пример. Список файлов:

```
iw1-201506.SAFE.safe
iw2-201507.SAFE.safe
iw1-201506.xml
iw2-201507.xml
```

Имена файлов добавить в следующий текст. Конечный результат который нужен:

```
 awk 'NR>1 {print $0}' < ../orig/iw1-201506.SAFE.safe > tmp_file
 cat ../orig/iw1-201506.xml tmp_file ../orig/m.xml > ./iw1-201506.xml
 awk 'NR>1 {print $0}' < ../orig/iw2-201507.SAFE.safe > tmp_file
 cat ../orig/iw2-201507.xml tmp_file ../orig/m.xml > ./iw2-201507.xml
 #и так далее
```

Как бы я мог это реализовать? Может быть можно обозначить строку и столбец в которую команда echo будет вставлять слово?

Также буду очень благодарен за ссылку на хороший мануал по данный теме.

Мой корявый пример но он полностью не реализован так как я не знаю как обозначить два разных формата и поэтому добавляет лишь одну строчку. Он сразу копирует имена файлов и вставляет вместе с текстом указанным ниже в файл, так как файлов может быть очень много.

```
for a in $(cd any/directory; ls *xml)
    do
       echo "cat ../orig/$a tmp_file ../orig/m.xml > ./$a" >> data.txt
    done
```

Comment: Не очень понятно чего вы хотите добиться в результате. Покажите содержимое источников и желаемый результат.

Comment: Добавил детали.

Comment: Не помогло. Вместо миллиона слов попробуйте сделать следующее: а) привести пример каталога с файлами, б) примеры файлов-источников, если таковые существуют (файлы **.safe*?),  в) результат, который ожидается.

Comment: А теперь понятнее стало?

Comment: Ага, ну смотрите, даю подсказки (мне лень писать полностью, а вам всё равно поучиться). 1. `find any/directory -type f -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.safe" -print0 | xargs -0`. 2. `man readlink; man realpath`. 3. File extension from name `echo ${fname#*.}`.